# Interview basic question

Tags: interviewing, internship

I'm applying for an internship position open for a security engineer position and I got asked some question in the preliminary phase that I don't know how to answer(probably it's just me) so I would like to know if some of you can help me.

The questions are:

1. Please confirm you want to be considered as a Security  Engineer
   Graduate with our Product Security Assessment & Analysis  Team?
2. If given an offer, when would you be available to start as a Full time Graduate?

I would respond to the first one with a "yes" since it's what I'm applying for, but I'm of the point of this question, since for me it was obvious.

With the second one I don't know what a Full Time Graduate is. (Do they mean to start working after the internship of what?)

Sorry for all this dumb questions

Comment: As I read, this is off-topic, because we cannot answer these questions _for_ you. Ask for clarification to the organization, as is your right.

Comment: I don't want an answer to this question, I just want some clarification on the question itself.

Comment: `Full Time Graduate` usually means, when you complete your studies (all courses and semesters) and have a graduate degree, but that may vary.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Thank you, that was what I was asking

Comment: With regards to the first question, while it seems odd because the answer appears obvious, it's not unusual for miscommunications to happen. People can turn up for interviews for slightly different positions to what they applied for due to these miscommunications. Eventually these are discovered of course, but it can waste a lot of time on both sides, so companies will often go out of their way to make it very clear that you understand exactly what position you are being considered for. As to the second question, I'd probably reach out to the company to clarify what they mean.

Comment: @malloc Please don't absolutely rely on what I'm saying, I'm no authority in _this_ case, talk to someone in the company you are interviewing for.

Comment: @SouravGhosh don't worry I'll ask anyways to the company.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Please confirm you want to be considered as a Security Engineer
>   Graduate with our Product Security Assessment & Analysis Team?

As daft as it sounds they are just dotting the i's and crossing the t's - getting confirmation that you are definitely applying for *this* position and you are agreeing to enter the application process. You'd be surprised how often it happens that you get "Oh but I thought I was being hired to be Chief Widget Wrangler!" It's kind of absurd but assuming the role listed is the correct one then just confirm that yes you want to be considered.

> If given an offer, when would you be available to start as a Full time Graduate?

They are protecting themselves - presumably they like to use internships as recruitment channels for full time workers. They are checking to make sure you haven't already accepted an offer for full time work after graduation or have something else already set in stone. This means they can prioritize giving opportunities to interns that they will at least have the *option* of hiring afterwards.